# enumerate object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, enumerate

How to enumerate object like below ? I don't know keys in advance, could be much more

```
{ '10.193.105.1': 
   { location: '02123',
     hostname: 'A0C2',
     contact: 'root@localhost' },
  '10.199.107.1': 
   { location: '01164',
     hostname: 'cp11',
     contact: 'me' } }
```

Comment: Object.keys(obj).forEach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object.keys gives you the object keys. Nest and loop

```js
var obj = {
  '10.193.105.1': {
    location: '02123',
    hostname: 'A0C2',
    contact: 'root@localhost'
  },
  '10.199.107.1': {
    location: '01164',
    hostname: 'cp11',
    contact: 'me'
  }
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach( function(key) {  //level one
    var child = obj[key];
    console.group(key);
    Object.keys(child).forEach( function (prop) {  //level two
        console.log(prop, ":", child[prop]);
    });
    console.groupEnd(key);  
} );
```

Comment: what's console.group or console.groupEnd ? In fact I have nodejs

Comment: It is logging methods...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/group Open up the developer console, Run the code above, look at your console.

Comment: sorry, how to do it in nodesjs ?

Comment: You do not need it to loop over the object. Add anything you want there. It was just for a demo. If you want to do groups in node use something like [this](https://github.com/rich-harris/node-console-group). Again, it is NOT needed. Change it to a normal console and delete the groupEnd line.